# Dropping Internet connection on Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I have continuous problems of network dropping connections on wifi with ubuntu 16.04, I have an ASUS R510J, this is my network card:

```
##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
        Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2161]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

`sudo service network-manager restart` doesnt's help, as I never regain internet connection after it drops, and I have to restart the PC. On Ethernet cable I have no problem.

What do you think is the issue? drivers?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,My network card is RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.I did the following steps to get it working:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Your WiFi will now work fine but you will need to re-install it after each kernel upgrade.
Or this code might work:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
```

Answer (score 1):

Install this driver from a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

It is a better driver that should support your adapter.

Comment: unfournately, I tried this solution for a few weeks and the problem persists. I assume it is just a matter of drivers

Comment: @perepepe, see my answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/917778/127308 on how to build the latest rtl wifi driver to solve this.