# Wifi problem in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, internet, lenovo, 17.04, realtek-wireless

Always a have problem when I install any version of ubuntu, but in this opportunity I can't solve the issue. My wifi connection down after 1 or 2 minutes in Ubuntu 17.04, it's so unstable, I already tried with:

```
apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

I have read so many articles in internet about the issue and nothing solve the problem, only change the time of issue ie the wifi get down in 2 minutes or in 10 minutes or in 1 more day but always get down, I do not know what doing. These are the tech features of my notebook when I execute these commands:

> lspci -nn

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
```

and

> lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]

Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

This is my kernel info:

> uname -mrs

```
Linux 4.10.0-20-generic x86_64
```

My notebook is a Lenovo 310-14IKB. I am not what more doing

Comment: `firmware-b43-installer` is only for some Broadcom devices. You have a Realtek.

Comment: Your problem is by no means unique.  I have the same problem with exactly the same card in a Lenovo Ideapad 110.
Even if I plug in an external USB wifi device, the problem is similar.  In my opinion it has to do with pushing a large volume of traffic through the device, then it stops working.  

Sometimes it can be restored by turning off the wifi and networking and then back on, but often restarting the notebook is the only solution.  Kernel 4.11.2-041102-generic

Comment: I already had realize that the traffic could affect because when I see videos the wifi  turn off, I did these [steps](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Az_cu_jZa2hmGxQSFfXwUbxeEAuIM_FvJ6xkj_dgRac/edit?usp=sharing) in mi pc and it runs a little bit better, I got those steps from a webside but in this moment I don´t remember where from, if someone knows the website please write it, my apologize to the author. @LifeBoy try those steps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are drivers that can be built and installed to fix this problem.

See https://medium.com/@elmaxx/rtl8821ae-wifi-drivers-in-ubuntu-16-04-4c1286524afa

The essence of the solution is:

```
lspci | grep Wireless
```

The system replies with the following line

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git 
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

These commands build and install the drivers for
rtl8192ce, rtl8192se, rtl8192de, rtl8188ee, rtl8192ee, rtl8723ae, rtl8723be, and rtl8821ae, all in one go.
Just in case the system doesn’t load the appropriate kernel module, you can execute the following command from within your rtlwifi_new directory

```
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

and reboot your system.

Note: I copied the above from the original article.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/714190)

Comment: I have update the answer accordingly

Comment: The instructions are for 16.04. Did anyone actually try this for 17.04?