# Can't connect to Wi-Fi on Ubuntu 17.10 (Realtek 8821AE Wireless)

Tags: wireless

I am dual booting (Win10/Ubuntu 17.10) and when i go to Ubuntu the wifi networks are there. When i click on one, they dissapear! All of them. And then i can't connect to the Wifi. This also happened in Kubuntu 17.04 when i had it.
[Here  is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VPYj.png)

Specs:

```
Network:
  *-generic DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: ff
       serial: c8:3d:d4:64:48:a5
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.13.0-16-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4000000-a4003fff
```

My laptop is Lenovo IdeaPad 510: https://www.cnet.com/products/ideapad-510-15-80sr002tus/specs/

[Picture of the wifi indicator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYlH4.png)

Wireless info trough cmd in Windows:

I managed to find some Wi-Fi card details with cmd trough windows:

```
 Name                   : Wi-Fi
 Description            : Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
 GUID                   : dbce393b-4e55-4f58-bde5-28a3861801ff
 Physical address       : c8:3d:d4:64:48:a5
 State                  : connected
 SSID                   : Network
 BSSID                  : 00:71:c2:32:4b:ec
 Network type           : Infrastructure
 Radio type             : 802.11n
 Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
 Cipher                 : CCMP
 Connection mode        : Profile
 Channel                : 8
 Receive rate (Mbps)    : 54
 Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 43.5
 Signal                 : 57%
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos upload results to paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL

Comment: I had a similar problem on my Ubuntu 16.04. Connecting an external wifi-adapter seemed to be the quickest working solution for me.

Comment: Have you installed any wireless drivers?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Where can i find those drivers?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Below i posted some wifi details that i got from windows CMD. My wireless card seems to be Realtek 8821AE Wireless

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropping Internet connection on Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796665/dropping-internet-connection-on-realtek-semiconductor-co-ltd-rtl8821ae)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I installed Linux Mint KDE and the wireless works good.