# "Enable Wifi" not showing

Tags: wireless

I recently used `sudo apt-get autoremove` command and after that "Enable Wifi" option is not showing.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae, wl

$ iwconfig is
lo no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

From `/var/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2017-11-06  01:15:38
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Requested-By: praveen (1000)
Remove: linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2), librpmsign3:amd64 (4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3), linux-image-extra-4.10.0-33-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-33.37~16.04.1),
librpmbuild3:amd64 (4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3),
linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-35.39~16.04.1),
debugedit:amd64 (4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3),
linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-33.37~16.04.1),
linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2),
linux-headers-4.10.0-35-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-35.39~16.04.1),
rpm:amd64 (4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3),
linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-33.37~16.04.1),
linux-headers-4.10.0-28:amd64 (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2),
linux-headers-4.10.0-33:amd64 (4.10.0-33.37~16.04.1),
linux-headers-4.10.0-35:amd64 (4.10.0-35.39~16.04.1),
linux-image-4.10.0-35-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-35.39~16.04.1),
linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic:amd64 (4.10.0-28.32~16.04.2)
End-Date: 2017-11-06  01:17:19
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${db:Status-Abbrev} ${Package;-40} ${Version}\n' linux-{image,headers}-\* | grep '^i'
ii  linux-headers-4.10.0-37                  4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1
ii  linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic          4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1
ii  linux-headers-4.10.0-38                  4.10.0-38.42~16.04.1
ii  linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic          4.10.0-38.42~16.04.1
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-98                   4.4.0-98.121
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic           4.4.0-98.121
ii  linux-headers-generic                    4.4.0.98.103
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04          4.10.0.38.40
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic            4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1
ii  linux-image-4.10.0-38-generic            4.10.0-38.42~16.04.1
ii  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic      4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1
ii  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-38-generic      4.10.0-38.42~16.04.1
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04            4.10.0.38.40
```

Comment: iwconfig command shows: lo no wireless extensions  enp1s0 no wireless extension

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/796665/dropping-internet-connection-on-realtek-semiconductor-co-ltd-rtl8821ae. The symptoms are different but the solution is ultimately the same: Install the suitable DKMS driver module. This would also provide the driver for new kernels automatically.

Comment: Thanks for all the data! Have an up-vote for the well informed question!

Comment: Thanks for your support sir. Can you please tell me what was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands will work for
rtl8192ce, rtl8192se, rtl8192de, rtl8188ee, rtl8192ee, rtl8723ae, rtl8723be, and rtl8821ae. If you have any other driver then please search and install.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git 
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

After that if your system does not load appropriate kernel module,you can run below command in same directory(make sure to run this for your specific driver in my case it is rtl8821ae):

```
sudo modprobe rtl8821ae
```

Comment: You should have used DKMS as the driver will need to be rebuilt after every kernel update.  `sudo dkms add ./rtwifi-new` might fix it

Comment: It says:`Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-rtwifi-new does not exist.`

Comment: Try `sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new`